# CSS - Validation - Red border on the left only cause the element to be offset

Tags: css

I'm a CSS newbie and I have trouble figuring how to solve this issue. If an input is invalid, I need to mark the input with a red border only on the left side.

My CSS looks like this:

```
input.ng-invalid {
    border-left-width: 10px;
    border-left-color: red;
}
```

It works fine except that it does add 10px to the width of the input and an invalid input is larger from a valid one.

[Example of my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZHyr.jpg)

Is there a way to keep the width for both a valid and invalid input exactly the same? I believe, I am not using the proper property to achieve what I want.

Comment: Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to styles of `input`.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman You rock, exactly what I needed!  Thanks.

Comment: why no one gave them likes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per initial suggestion, you can use CSS `box-sizing` property by setting it up to value of `border-box`, which means that all elements sizing's calculation will include values of `borders`, `paddings` and `heights` and `widths`. But you'll also need to fix the `width` (or `height`) of element, as in the example below:

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.invalid {
  border-left-width: 10px;
  border-left-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type=text />
<br />
<br />
<input type=text class=invalid />
```

PS. `border-color: transparent` sounds a bit like a hack

Comment: why no one gave them likes?

Answer (score 1):

What may be happening is that your normal elements do not have a border around it by default. If that's the case, you're actually introducing a border around your elements.

What you may need to do is the following.

```
<html>
 <body>
  <input value='Valid' /><br />
  <input class='ng-invalid' value='InValid' />
 </body>
</html>

<style>
 input{ border-left-width: 10px; border-left-color: transparent; } /*now all borders has a left transparent border of 10*/
 input.ng-invalid { border-left-width: 10px; border-left-color: red; }
</style>
```

Comment: why no one gave them likes?

Answer (score 1):

i made a snippet for you please check below link:
https://jsfiddle.net/fatehjagdeo/sx9g3yLs/

or check this below code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>demo</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<style>
.ng-invalid {
    border-left-width: 10px;
    border-left-color: red;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).on('click','#submit',function(){
$('input').removeClass('ng-invalid');
var value=$('#name').val();
if(value==""){
$('#name').addClass('ng-invalid');
}
});
</script>
</head>
 <body>
  <input  id="name" /><br />
 <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why no one gave them likes?